# Where to find report for XCode UITests started from commandline

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, xcode-ui-testing, xcode7.3

I am looking for a way to open report after tests started from commandline has been finished.

Tests were started using commandline:

```
xcodebuild -scheme "Application Test Schema" -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6s Plus,OS=9.3' test
```

In the end of testing I have listed test cases that are failed:

```
Test Suite 'AppUITests.xctest' failed at 2016-07-11 12:00:10.376.
     Executed 17 tests, with 1 failure (0 unexpected) in 389.167 (389.217) seconds
Test Suite 'Selected tests' failed at 2016-07-11 12:00:10.377.
     Executed 17 tests, with 1 failure (0 unexpected) in 389.167 (389.219) seconds
Failing tests:
    -[MainScreenTests test14_ClickOnButtonOpensKeyboard()]
```

I want to figure out whats happened to test "test14_ClickOnButtonOpensKeyboard", read stacktrace, etc... Where I can find report for this run?

I checked XCode Report Navigator history and it does not contain last run started from command line.

XCode version 7.3.1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37283647/where-is-the-screenshot-file-from-xcode-ui-test

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Logs are save under your derived data folder

Typically `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<mangled app folder>/Logs/Test/`. Take a look at xcodebuild's logs to find out the exact location.

Under the `Test` folder you'll find a plist with the entire test sequence. You should navigate the keys Root > TestableSummaries > Tests > Item n > Subtests all down to the ActivitySummaries key which will contain the single steps including a reference to screenshots that are contained in the `Attachments` folder.

If you don't care about the structured information stored in the plist and just need a raw text log you can also check the folder with the same name of the plist which contains a log file per test session.

P.S. If you're wondering why the derive data folder grows so much after each test, take a look at the `Attachment` folder size...

Comment: Awesome, thank you Tomas! I also found this post, that could be useful for someone who wants to look at it in details: http://michele.io/test-logs-in-xcode