# XCUIApplication replacements for UIATarget captureScreenWithName()

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation, xcode-ui-testing

We are trying to migrate from UIAutomation to XCUITests and did use the captureScreenWithName() API to programmatically generate screen shots.
What is the replacement in the XCUITests ?
(I know that automatically screenshots are taken in case of error, but we have a special test which runs forever in a loop and evaluates QA click,tap commands via network similar to the appium-xcuitest-driver https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver)
Do I need to rip out private headers (XCAXClient_iOS.h) like the appium guys did in order to get a screenshot API?

**Edit**
I used the actual code line for the accepted solution from 
https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/snapshot/lib/assets/SnapshotHelper.swift and its just this for IOS

```
 XCUIDevice.sharedDevice().orientation = .Unknown
```

or in objC

```
[XCUIDevice sharedDevice].orientation =UIInterfaceOrientationUnknown;
```

I use a process on the host to lookup in the "Logs/Test/Attachments" directory all Screenshot_*.png files before the call , and find the new shot then after the call as the new file added in this directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gestures (taps, swipes, scrolls...) cause screenshots, and screenshots are also often taken while locating elements or during assessing expectations.

Fastlane's snapshot tool uses a rotation to an unknown orientation to trigger a screenshot event (which has no effect on the app): https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/snapshot - you can use this if you want to be in control of some screenshots.